# print a list of dict and corresponding key as comma seperated values

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have following `dict`:

```py
data = {
        'A': [{1.0: 133.0}, {4.0: 126.0}], 
        'B': [{1.0: 153.0}, {4.0: 16.0}],
        'C': [{1.0: 9.0}, {4.0: 12.0}]
       }
```

I need the output as follows:

```
A, 1.0, 133.0
A, 4.0, 126.0
B, 1.0, 153.0
B, 4.0, 16.0
C, 1.0, 9.0
C, 4.0, 12.0
```

This is my attempt (working):

```py
with open("super.csv", "w") as f:
    for k, v in data.items():
        for a in v:
            f.write(k + ", " + "".join('{}, {}'.format(k1,v1) for k1,v1 in a.items()) + "\n")
```

I am unable to make this better (more concise), please help. Can I avoid using `join`?

Comment: *Can I avoid using `join`?* why? Any specific reason?

Comment: Define "*better*"

Comment: @shaikmoeed Not really. It looks super lengthy that's all. I am wondering whether there is a simple way of printing `key, value` of a dict as csv

Comment: Why are you using `join` in the first place when all the input dicts have only one key-value pair? and more importantly, CSV rows should all have the same number of columns.

Comment: @wjandrea my csv rows have same number of columns. Also I am not sure how to print `key, value` without dict comprehension that's why I used join

Comment: @Patio What I'm trying to say is, if you ever had an input `a` with more than one key-value pair, it would break the CSV. Is that intentional?

Comment: @wjandrea Understood your point. I think No, it will be always like `A: [{a : b},...]` for each entry. The inner dict is like a tuple now that I think about it, but this `data` is returned by another function. I cannot change that impl.

Comment: So then you could unpack the single pair like this: `[[k1, v1]] = a.items()`

Comment: Are you aware you can print to a file like this? `print(..., file=f)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use `k1,v1 = list(a.items())[0]` instead of `((k1,v1),) = a.items()`
and also you can use `print(f"{k}, {k1}, {v1}",file=f)` so that `"\n"` already impleminted

```py
with open("super.csv", "w") as f:
    for k, v in data.items():
        for a in v:
            ((k1,v1),) = a.items()
            print(f"{k}, {k1}, {v1}",file=f)
```

Comment: Deleted my prev comment about unpacking. Very clever (in my PO). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is another way to do the same without using `join`

(Assuming, your data structure won't change as mentioned by OP under post comments)

```
data = {
        'A': [{1.0: 133.0}, {4.0: 126.0}], 
        'B': [{1.0: 153.0}, {4.0: 16.0}],
        'C': [{1.0: 9.0}, {4.0: 12.0}]
       }

flat_dict = lambda x: [f"{k}, {v}" for k, v in x.items()][0]
for key, values in data.items():
    for item in values:
        print(f"{key}, {flat_dict(item)}")
```

---

**Output:**

```
A, 1.0, 133.0
A, 4.0, 126.0
B, 1.0, 153.0
B, 4.0, 16.0
C, 1.0, 9.0
C, 4.0, 12.0
```